# Javascript function into a loop, Django app

Tags: javascript, django, facebook, loops

In my Django app I display a list of facebook friends. I would like to associate a facebook invite button for each of those friends.
For that I wan't to use a javascript function that allows me to invite a friend, and then pass this function into a loop.

Here is my html code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
{% for friend in group %}  
<p>{{ friend.name }} <a href='#' onclick="FacebookInviteOneFriend('{{friend.uid}}');"> Invite</a></p>       
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

And my javascript code:

```
FB.init({
appId:XXXX,
cookie:true,
status:true,
xfbml:true
});

function FacebookInviteOneFriend(UserId)
{
FB.ui({
method: 'apprequests',
message: 'My message'
to: UserId
});
}
```

It doesn't work that way. I' don't know javascript so I don't find where my mistake is.

Any help would be welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try placing single quotes around `{{friend.uid}}`

```
onclick="FacebookInviteOneFriend('{{friend.uid}}');"
```

Also try adding a debug statement to your function to see what, if any, value is being passed:

```
function FacebookInviteOneFriend(UserId) {
    alert(UserId);

    FB.ui({
        method: 'apprequests',
        message: 'My message'
        to: UserId
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but nothing changes, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you post a more complete version of your source code? Did the alert display the `UserId` value? If not, were there any javascript error messages?

Comment: No, the alert didn't display the UserId value. And there was no javascript error message. For the source code, I edited to show you my whole js code.

Comment: I would remove the Facebook pieces until you can get the `alert(UserId)` to display something. As an example, you should be seeing something like this when the link is clicked: http://jsbin.com/eroway/1/ Without seeing the full source to get a bigger picture to what is going on, I'm just going to be guessing.

Comment: Ok, I tried again, using the quotes, now it's working. I don't know what happened the first time. Thank you very much for your help.